# Java Applet reading external license.xml file

Tags: java, applet

I am using Java Applet to connect Littmann 3200 stethoscope and trying to access its data

The application is running fine in applet viewer but when I try to run it on browser it is not reading provided license.xml file by the device vendor. the file is placed inside the .jar file. I also placed license.xml file in the same folder where i placed tha .jar,.class and my html page but my application is unable to read the license.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Not much we can do; you're going to have to ask the vendor if their jar file works in applets. It may not.